# iostream library doesn't work using Qt's cmake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, iostream, unhandled-exception

I have recently set up Qt6 with CLion in order to start making small GUI's. However when i first tried to add some console outputs using the "cout". my code exits with code (0xC0000005)...

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(Simple_GUI)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

#=============== INCLUSION OF Qt ================#
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\\Qt\\6.5.2\\mingw_64\\lib\\cmake")

find_package(Qt6Core REQUIRED) #find needed packages
find_package(Qt6Widgets REQUIRED)

#=========== ADDING EXECUTABLE AND LINKING LIBRARIES ============#
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt6::Widgets)
```

and here is main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    std::string h("Hello World");
    qDebug() << h;
    std::cout << h << std::endl;

    //==========Minimal source code of a Qt application=====:
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv); 

    return QCoreApplication::exec();
}
```

the moment i take out the std::cout << ... line, everything works fine again. qDebug() works as well.

edit: here's the gdb output:

[image]

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace from a debugger? What exactly generates this segfault?

Comment: I will test in msys2. Edit: it compiled and run with no problems. My guess is you have [dll hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell)

Comment: Console output in Windows GUI mode applications generally doesn't work and people often need to jump through hoops to re-enable it (although it doesn't normally crash like in your case).

Comment: Try Dependency Walker and Process Explorer tools. For Process Explorer, you can try adding a pause before the crashing line, such as the ugly yet perfect for the purpose `system("pause");`, so you can see which libraries are loaded. Chances are, libraries from some wrong directory get loaded. You can consider removing that directory from the PATH (even uninstalling), or you can copy the correct libraries to same directory where th .exe is.